# Compare two identical strings fails in javascript

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I have the below function. It always says the text does not match. This is within test complete. I have put a watch on both items and both dont contain any white spaces. I am new to this but wondered if there is anything obvious I am doing wrong?

```
function VerifyComboBox(/*formcontrolname, value*/)
{
var formcontrolname = "CassetteTypeFilter";
var value = "Filter By Cassette Type";

 try{ 
      /*Boolean condition is declare either to execute code or not*/
    if (formcontrolname && value !== null)
    {
     /*convert String to object */ 
    var name = ConvertToObject(formcontrolname);

    object=Sys.Browser("*").Page("*").FindChildByXPath("//*[@formcontrolname='" + name + "' and contains(., '" + value + "')]");    


    /*Waits until object appears*/
    waitUntilObjectIsVisible("//*[@formcontrolname='" + name + "']");    


    /*scrolll to the invisble element*/
    object.ScrollIntoView();
    var visibleText = object.innerText.replace(/▼/g,'')


    /*Boolean conditions to check the value of the element*/
    if (visibleText == value) {
     Log.Checkpoint("Text matches");
     }
     else {
     Log.Error("Text does not match");
     }
     }
    }
 catch (e)
    {
       // Posts an exception message to the test log`enter code here`
       Log["Error"]("EXCEPTION OCCURED: " + e["description"]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the values for `visibleText` and `value` at the time of `if (visibleText == value) {`? - What does `console.log(visibleText)` and `console.log(value)` show you?

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: Added a picture above

Answer (score 0):

TestComplete gives you `aqString` in order to avoid this kind of things. Use `aqString.Compare` in order to compare strings properly.